# Ruby amazon acs API change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I had received a mail from amazon API services that after oct 25 2011, all requests to API should have a associate tag.

I'm using the ruby gem amazon ACS(for item search from amazon) for one of my app. Is that will be affected due to API change.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to sign up as an associate and pass your api calls an associate tag as a  parameter. [Sign up Here](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html)

Comment: Hi..I'm already using a amazon account with access  key and security key. Is it possible to update older account?

Comment: yes you still need those keys, but now you also need associate tag. Separate sign up.